# curl or wget - resume download on network error and on session ended

Tags: wget

I'm wondering if there is a way to dump an HTTP stream no matter what happens on the server side.
If I use `curl --retry 999` or `wget --retry-connrefused --waitretry=1 --read-timeout=20 --timeout=15 -t 0`, the connection and download are resumed in case of network errors, but if the session is terminated by the server there is no retry. The connection is being ended and that's it. I need a perpetual retry even on FIN.

Do wget or curl have some special parameters to archive this?
Is there a tool that is not wget or curl that can archive this? A single command would be appreciated since the output is being piped.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid local failure or so, you can put it into while loop, bash script

```
while [ 1 ]; do
wget -t 0 --timeout=15 --waitretry=1 --read-timeout=20 --retry-connrefused --continue
if [ $? = 0 ]; then break; fi; # check return value, break if successful
sleep 1s;
done;
```

You may try also another solution

```
FILENAME=$1
DOWNURL=$2
wget -O "`echo $FILENAME`" "`echo $DOWNURL`"
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")
while [ $FILESIZE \< 1000 ]; do
    sleep 3
    wget -O "`echo $FILENAME`" "`echo $DOWNURL`"
    FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")
done
```

You can play with the limit 1000. If the file is smaller then the while loop will try again.